# VSCode error pop up: unable to connect gopls server error

Tags: go, gopls

i was facing an unexpected error on vscode when trying to use golang. It ask me to install gopls but unfortunately it failed at the end

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYhWS.png)

Is there any solution to solve it?

To solve it without any issues

Comment: Take a look at this GitHub issue, maybe a fix is in there for you: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2743

Comment: @gonutz it's still not working T>T